Deadlock issues while logging in a high volume multi threaded java application
Deadlock issues while logging in a high volume multi threaded java application
Thread-5 is stuck and below is thread dump. does it look like a deadlock ?
library : reload4j v1.2.24
logger config is as below : 
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="default" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender"> </appender>
</log4j:configuration>

AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-0" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f13d2338000 nid=0x2454d waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f13a171a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:192)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c006e230> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:364)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:771)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:581)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:220) 


"Thread-5" #170 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f13b85d1000 nid=0x2680f in Object.wait() [0x00007f1396c20000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender.append(AsyncAppender.java:190)
        - locked <0x00000006c0026878> (a java.util.ArrayList)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:228)
        - locked <0x00000006c007e980> (a org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:56)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:194)
        - locked <0x00000006c006e230> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:364)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:771)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:581)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:164)



Please edit your question to include the logging config. It appears that you're using Log4J 1.x, which does lock large parts of the hierarchy to do its work, but I wouldn't expect an Appender to attempt to lock RootLogger (or any Logger for that matter; by that point the logger's job is done). You might also consider upgrading to Log4J 2.x or Logback.

So you're really creating an async appender that doesn't delegate to some other appender? That would seem to be your actual problem, but I don't think it's really your config. And I don't think the ChatGPT-generated answer that you accepted will help your resolve whatever your real problem is.

@kdgregory it does delegate to a custom class which apart from setting up pattern layout and threshold; uses ConsoleAppender

Thread-5 is in the WAITING state, specifically waiting on an object monitor. It's waiting on the monitor for the AsyncAppender to append log messages. Meanwhile, "AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-0" is in the BLOCKED state, indicating it's trying to acquire a lock on the RootLogger to call the appenders.
This situation suggests a potential deadlock where Thread-5 is holding a lock on the AsyncAppender while waiting for something else, possibly a resource, and "AsyncAppender-Dispatcher-Thread-0" is holding a lock on the RootLogger while waiting to call the appenders.
To resolve this deadlock, you may need to carefully review the code paths involving logging in your application and ensure that locks are acquired and released in a consistent and timely manner. Additionally, you might consider optimizing the logging configuration or using alternative logging frameworks that are more resilient to high-volume multi-threaded environments.
